# Wierd C++ Problems, OpenGL game

Tags: c++, opengl

Aight so, I'm in the process of making a simple terrain program, not exactly a game, but hey maybe someday. I'll start with describing the basics of how my program works. I'm using an two-dimension array to store the coordinates of the vertexes which make up a grid of triangles. The x and z values are assigned in the follow code:

```
    //Sets up the array for the vertexes

int e = 0;
int p = 0;
for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)    {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        grid[p][0] = x * 2;
        grid[p][2] = e;
        p++;
    }
    e += 2;
}
```

Okay, so the grid array is the one I use for storing the values of all the vertexes in the program, the first argument (the value in the first set of []) is used to choose a point, the second set of [] is the x, y, and z values, the code snippet above only sets values for the x and z coordinates. 
The y value, height, is randomised at the start of the program using the following code:

```
    //Random heights for the terrain

if (fir == true)    {

    for (int h = 0; h < 64; h++)    {
        grid[h][1] = rand() % 3;
    }

    fir = false;
}
```

And the code for drawing the triangles:

```
        for (int q = 0; q < 11; q++)    {

        a = q * 5;
        b = a + 1;
        c = a + 5;

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

        for (int dw = 0; dw < 8; dw++)  {

            //a
            glColor3f(grid[a][1], grid[a][1], grid[a][1]);
            glVertex3f(grid[a][0], grid[a][1], grid[a][2]);

            //b
            glColor3f(grid[b][1], grid[b][1], grid[b][1]);
            glVertex3f(grid[b][0], grid[b][1], grid[b][2]);

            //c
            glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
            glVertex3f(grid[c][0], grid[c][1], grid[c][2]);

            a = c;
            t = b;
            b = a + 1;
            c = t;

        }
        glEnd();
    }
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't make the size of the grid bigger without the program breaking, I would like to be able to change the size of the grid of triangles to whatever I like. when I try to change the for loop which goes through the x values (first code snippet) the program breaks, my movement speed drastically increases, moving the mouse has no effect on the camera rotation. When I do manage to find a set of values to work the grid of triangles is messed up, any points after the 5th row are all set to 0, I'll post the whole program, I don't know if it will run for everyone, but I think the problem is something that requires the whole program to be looked at in order to solve.
I think the problem may be due to variables being shared by different parts of the program, I have looked and looked but can't seem to find any cause. This is my last resort to solving this nightmare of a problem...

### main.cpp

```
    /*








*/


#include <iostream>
#include <glut.h>
#include <gl\GL.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "vector3f.h"

using namespace std;

//Variables
const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720;
const char* WINDOW_TITLE = "Terrain";

const float WALKING_SPEED = 5.0;
const float MOUSE_SENSITIVITY = 0.3;
const float MAX_TILT = 90.0;

float grid[200][3];

float LAST_TIME;
float CURRENT_TIME;
float DELTA_TIME;

bool KEY[256];

int a;
int b;
int c;
int t;

int MOUSE_LAST_X;
int MOUSE_LAST_Y;

int MOUSE_CURRENT_X;
int MOUSE_CURRENT_Y;

int MOUSE_DELTA_X;
int MOUSE_DELTA_Y;

float red;
float green;
float blue;



bool fir = true;

//Object
vector3f CAMERA_POSITION;
vector3f CAMERA_ROTATION;

//Functions
void initialize();
void display();
void reshape(int w, int h);
void keyboardDown(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void keyboardUp(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void mouseMove(int x, int y);
void movement();
double degreesToRadians(double degrees);
double dsin(double theta);
double dcos(double theta);
double dtan(double theta);

void display() {



    //cout << KEY[' '] << endl;

    movement();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //Camera transformations
    glRotatef(CAMERA_ROTATION.x, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(CAMERA_ROTATION.y, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(CAMERA_ROTATION.z, 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(-CAMERA_POSITION.x, -CAMERA_POSITION.y, CAMERA_POSITION.z);

    //Draw the basic triangle
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -3.0);

        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, -3.0);

        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(10.0, -1.0, -3.0);
    glEnd();

    /*

    1  0,0,0
    2  2,0,0
    3  4,0,0
    4  6,0,0

    5  0,0,2
    6  2,0,2
    7  4,0,2
    8  6,0,2

    9  0,0,4
    10 2,0,4
    11 4,0,4
    12 6,0,4

    13 0,0,6
    14 2,0,6
    15 4,0,6
    16 6,0,6

    */



    /*//Option 1 (2 for loops, four if statements)
    for (int p = 0; p < 16; p++)    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x += 2)  {
            grid[p][0] = x;
        }
        grid[p][1] = 0;
        if (p < 4)  {
            grid[p][2] = 0;
        }
        if (p < 8 && p >= 4)    {
            grid[p][2] = 2;
        }
        if (p < 12 && p >= 8)   {
            grid[p][2] = 4;
        }
        if (p < 16 && p >= 12)  {
            grid[p][2] = 6;
        }
    }
    */
    //Option 2 (three for loops)


    //Sets up the array for the vertexes

    int e = 0;
    int p = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            grid[p][0] = x * 2;
            grid[p][2] = e;
            p++;
        }
        e += 2;
    }


    //Random heights for the terrain

    if (fir == true)    {

        for (int h = 0; h < 64; h++)    {
            grid[h][1] = rand() % 3;
        }

        fir = false;
    }




    //cout << "point 0: " << grid[0][0] << ", " << grid[0][1] << ", " << grid[0][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 1: " << grid[1][0] << ", " << grid[1][1] << ", " << grid[1][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 2: " << grid[2][0] << ", " << grid[2][1] << ", " << grid[2][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 3: " << grid[3][0] << ", " << grid[3][1] << ", " << grid[3][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 4: " << grid[4][0] << ", " << grid[4][1] << ", " << grid[4][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 5: " << grid[5][0] << ", " << grid[5][1] << ", " << grid[5][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 6: " << grid[6][0] << ", " << grid[6][1] << ", " << grid[6][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 7: " << grid[7][0] << ", " << grid[7][1] << ", " << grid[7][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 8: " << grid[8][0] << ", " << grid[8][1] << ", " << grid[8][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 9: " << grid[9][0] << ", " << grid[9][1] << ", " << grid[9][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 10: " << grid[10][0] << ", " << grid[10][1] << ", " << grid[10][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 11: " << grid[11][0] << ", " << grid[11][1] << ", " << grid[11][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 12: " << grid[12][0] << ", " << grid[12][1] << ", " << grid[12][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 13: " << grid[13][0] << ", " << grid[13][1] << ", " << grid[13][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 14: " << grid[14][0] << ", " << grid[14][1] << ", " << grid[14][2] << endl;
    //cout << "point 15: " << grid[15][0] << ", " << grid[15][1] << ", " << grid[15][2] << endl;





        for (int q = 0; q < 11; q++)    {

            a = q * 5;
            b = a + 1;
            c = a + 5;

            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

            for (int dw = 0; dw < 8; dw++)  {

                //a
                glColor3f(grid[a][1], grid[a][1], grid[a][1]);
                glVertex3f(grid[a][0], grid[a][1], grid[a][2]);

                //b
                glColor3f(grid[b][1], grid[b][1], grid[b][1]);
                glVertex3f(grid[b][0], grid[b][1], grid[b][2]);

                //c
                glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                glVertex3f(grid[c][0], grid[c][1], grid[c][2]);

                a = c;
                t = b;
                b = a + 1;
                c = t;

            }
            glEnd();
        }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void keyboardDown(unsigned char key, int x, int y)  {

    KEY[key] = true;

}

void keyboardUp(unsigned char key, int x, int y)    {

    KEY[key] = false;

}

void movement() {

    CURRENT_TIME = ((float)glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000);
    DELTA_TIME = CURRENT_TIME - LAST_TIME;
    LAST_TIME = CURRENT_TIME;

    MOUSE_DELTA_X = MOUSE_CURRENT_X - MOUSE_LAST_X;
    MOUSE_DELTA_Y = MOUSE_CURRENT_Y - MOUSE_LAST_Y;

    MOUSE_LAST_X = MOUSE_CURRENT_X;
    MOUSE_LAST_Y = MOUSE_CURRENT_Y;

    CAMERA_ROTATION.y += (float)MOUSE_DELTA_X * MOUSE_SENSITIVITY;
    CAMERA_ROTATION.x += (float)MOUSE_DELTA_Y * MOUSE_SENSITIVITY;

    if (CAMERA_ROTATION.x > MAX_TILT)   {
        CAMERA_ROTATION.x = MAX_TILT;
    }
    if (CAMERA_ROTATION.x < -MAX_TILT)  {
        CAMERA_ROTATION.x = -MAX_TILT;
    }


    if (KEY['w'] == true)   {
        CAMERA_POSITION.x += (WALKING_SPEED * DELTA_TIME) * dsin(CAMERA_ROTATION.y);
        CAMERA_POSITION.z += (WALKING_SPEED * DELTA_TIME) * dcos(CAMERA_ROTATION.y);
        CAMERA_POSITION.y += (WALKING_SPEED * DELTA_TIME) * dsin(CAMERA_ROTATION.x + 180);
    }
    if (KEY['s'] == true)   {
        CAMERA_POSITION.x += (WALKING_SPEED * DELTA_TIME) * dsin(CAMERA_ROTATION.y + 180);
        CAMERA_POSITION.z += (WALKING_SPEED * DELTA_TIME) * dcos(CAMERA_ROTATION.y + 180);
        CAMERA_POSITION.y += (WALKING_SPEED * DELTA_TIME) * dsin(CAMERA_ROTATION.x);
    }
    if (KEY['a'] == true)   {
        CAMERA_POSITION.x += (WALKING_SPEED * DELTA_TIME) * dsin(CAMERA_ROTATION.y + 270);
        CAMERA_POSITION.z += (WALKING_SPEED * DELTA_TIME) * dcos(CAMERA_ROTATION.y + 270);
    }
    if (KEY['d'] == true)   {
        CAMERA_POSITION.x += (WALKING_SPEED * DELTA_TIME) * dsin(CAMERA_ROTATION.y + 90);
        CAMERA_POSITION.z += (WALKING_SPEED * DELTA_TIME) * dcos(CAMERA_ROTATION.y + 90);
    }
    if (KEY[' '] == true)   {
        CAMERA_POSITION.y += (WALKING_SPEED * DELTA_TIME);
    }
    if (KEY['e'] == true)   {
        exit(1);
    }

}

void mouseMove(int x, int y)    {

    MOUSE_CURRENT_X = x;
    MOUSE_CURRENT_Y = y;



}

double degreesToRadians(double degrees){

    return degrees * M_PI / 180;

}

double dsin(double theta)   {

    return sin(degreesToRadians(theta));

}
double dcos(double theta)   {

    return cos(degreesToRadians(theta));

}
double dtan(double theta)   {

    return tan(degreesToRadians(theta));

}


void reshape(int w, int h)  {

    //Stops the ratio from dividing by 0
    if (h == 0) {
        h = 1;
    }

    float fRatio = (float)w / h;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gluPerspective(60, fRatio, 0.1, 1000);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}

void initialize() {

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 102.0 / 255.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

int main(int iArgc, char** cArgv) {

    //Initialise OpenGL and GLUT
    glutInit(&iArgc, cArgv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    //Setup window
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE);

    //Setup GLUT callback functions
    initialize();
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardDown);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyboardUp);
    glutMotionFunc(mouseMove);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouseMove);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    //Enter main loop
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm very confused (and this code is quite confusing - my advice more methods, clearer variable names, tidy up whitespace, add comments etc) - `a = q * 5;` and `c = a + 5;` - does this not effectively limit you to a 5 wide grid?

Comment: Either way, my first advice would be to turn this: `float grid[200][3];` into this `float grid[rows][columns][3];` and refactor accordingly.

Comment: Rather than having a two dimensional array, I suggest using a `std::vector<Coordinate>`, where `Coordinate` is a struct containing the coordinate values.  This would make your program more readable and less prone to defects.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick remarks:

- your loops access different number of points!
  1st loop (r, x) initialize 50 points
  2nd loop (h) initialize 64 points
  3rd loop (q, dw) access 59 points
- glColor3f values should be between 0 and 1 but, using your grid y values, you get 0, 1 or 2
- beware of the [gimbal lock problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) when trying to rotate your view!